# TFS Lifecycle Management for Build Environment

Tags: tfs, msbuild

How would you manage the lifecycle and automated build process when some of the projects (`C#` *.csproj* projects) are part of the actual build system?

**Example:**
A *.csproj* is a project that uses `MSBuild` tasks that are implemented in *BuildEnv.csproj*.
Both projects are part of the same product (meaning, *BuildEnv.csproj* frequently changes as the product is being developed and not a 3rd party that is rarely updated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must factor this out into two separate "projects" otherwise you'll spend ages chasing your tail trying to find out if a broken build is due to changes in the build system or chages in the code being developed.

Previously we've factored the two systems out into separate projects in CVS.

You want to be able to vary one thing while keeping the other constant to limit what you would have to look at when performing forensic analysis.

Hope that helps.